# Intersections of the B-orbits and the orbits of some other Borel subgroups in the flag variety G/B

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, flag-varieties

This is a follow-up of this previous question below:

[Intersections of $B$ and $B^-$ orbits in the flag variety $G/B$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/193867/intersections-of-b-and-b-orbits-in-the-flag-variety-g-b)

Let $G = SL_n(\mathbb{C})$, $B$ be the standard Borel subgroup, and consider some other Borel subgroups $wBw^{-1}$, for some $w$ in the Weyl group $W$. When $w$ is the longest element $w_0$, we have $wBw^{-1}$ is just the opposite Borel $B^-$.

How much is known about the geometry of the intersections of the $B$ and $wBw^{-1}$ orbits? I know that the intersection will not be transverse except when $w = w_0$. Are these intersections affine? Are they equi-dimensional? What are their dimensions? Any references?